# What does pip install . (dot) mean?

Tags: python, pip

I have a shell script whose last line is:

```
pip install .
```

What does it do?

- `pip install <package-name>` installs the specified package
- `pip install -r requirements.txt` installs all packages specified in `requirements.txt`

But I am not sure what the above command does.

Comment: Note to self - this way requires a setup.py file which lists what's needed

Comment: I personally use the code . command to hop into my workflow.  It's useful if you already use vscode.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

"Install the project found in the current directory".

This is just a specific case of `pip install /path/to-source/tree`.

---

To quote the [the `pip install` documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#usage) describing this usage:

> ```
> pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
> ```

Answer (score 37):

Explicitly, `pip install .` will execute the [`setup.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/) file in the current directory (which will usually load a `requirements.txt` file).

Comment: For me, I had to use `pip install -e .`, otherwise it was creating an undesired `build` dir.

Answer (score 0):

The dot notation in the `pip install` dependency is similar to: `python3 setup.py develop`