# Error installing FinRL: Could not build wheels for box2d-py

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, finrl

I want to run this code https://github.com/AI4Finance-Foundation/FinRL-Tutorials/blob/master/2-Advance/FinRL_Ensemble_StockTrading_ICAIF_2020.ipynb

The problem is that, when I run:

```
from finrl.config_tickers import DOW_30_TICKER
```

,
it tells me: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'finrl'`

I tried to do it by following de steps in the point 4.3 of this document: `https://finrl.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/`, but when I do

```
git clone https://github.com/AI4Finance-Foundation/FinRL.git

cd FinRL

pip install .
```

it gives me this error: `ERROR: Could not build wheels for box2d-py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Comment: `pip install .` ? Please post the whole code. Consider adding tag finrl: it exists!

Comment: I have just changed it. Sorry and thank you! I am a python beginner :)

Comment: Related, by the way: [What does pip install . (dot) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39023758/12846804) so that's ok but are you sure you have a correct Python or pip version to run that install? Probably ask github author

Comment: Here was the answer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMgj4pSHLww

Comment: Good, well if you feel like taking the time to help future readers, you may self-answer, with the steps you took and the link as support. But do mention your system and config